# Audio still playing when the modal is closed

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

[image: Current OutPUT]When I click on the "**Close**" Button on the **modal**,the **audio** of the youtube video is still playing in the background.

## Current Code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"  data-original-title="Learn How to Use Communication Assistant "  data-placement="bottom"  data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#myModal">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
               <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">How To Use Communication Assistant</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yzi2I4blCoE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

### current Output

After Clicking on the Close button the audio is still playing in the background.

## Expected Output

When i click on the "**close**" Button both the **modal** and **video** should close.

Comment: please post a snippet working

Answer (score 1):

You can consider trying this code:

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", $("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));
});
```